# CSS box-shadow property adjustment

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a box based on this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NKcm.png

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/qiwaq/1/edit

...but the border still seems a little of. What am I missing?

Comment: Set border color little Dark black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify **box-shadow** value set h-shadow **2px**, v-shadow **2px**, blur **10px** and spread **0px**

```
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgb(41, 41, 41);
```

#### box-shadow Syntax

```
 box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color;
```

#### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>CSS Box</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="the-box">
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS code

```
.the-box {
   background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
   border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgb(41, 41, 41);
   width: 518px;
   height: 330px;
   margin-top: 10%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
```

}

#### Demo [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/moneqepa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.the-box {
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgb(41, 41, 41);
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px rgb(41, 41, 41);
  width: 518px;
  height: 330px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

you have to play with box-shadow property a little bit.

here is the CSS very near to your posted image.

```
.the-box {
  background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgb(41, 41, 41);
  width: 518px;
  height: 330px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsbin.com/sefulaxo/1/edit